# When to call createRecord and how to handle store transactions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I just started with Ember.js and have a very simple flow I'd like to implement.

On an overview screen I have a new button that allows the user to add a record. Upon saving the user is returned to the overview screen where he sees the newly created record in the overview.

The user navigates to the "new record" page using a linkTo

```
{{#linkTo locations.new}} Insert location {{/linkTo}}
```

This triggers the following route where a new model is prepared so that it can be bound to the screen.

```
App.LocationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Location.createRecord();
  }
});
```

The handlebars template for the new location screen looks like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="locations/new">
   <h1>New location</h1>
   Latitude :  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="latitude"}}
   Longitude : {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="longitude"}}
   <p><button {{action addItem this}}>Add record</button></p>
</script>
```

The addItem is implemented like this:

```
App.LocationsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  addItem: function(location) {
    this.get("store").commit();
    this.get("target").transitionTo("locations");

  }
});
```

A couple of issues I encountered with this :

**Model store transactions**

- As soon as the user navigates (using linkTo) to the new location page an empty record is created (using createRecord). I believe this is required to bind the controls to the model.
- I noticed that when the user fills in a latitude, but decides to return to the overview (using a linkTo), the partially filled model is put into the overview.
- Refreshing the page removes the partially filled object

I've noticed this a lot while working in Ember.js ... the difference between transitioning to a new route via linkTo and refreshing it in the browser is sometimes huge.

Question : what pattern do I need to use to implement the "Add new record" flow. I simply want to navigate to a new screen and have a save / cancel button. I only want the record added when clicking save. Should createRecord only be called when clicking Save, but then how do I bind the controls ?

**Model duplicates**

When my REST service returned the following (non ember.js standard) JSON after doing a POST (adding a record):

```
{
  "latitude": "1.123",
  "longitude": "1.123",
  "accuracy": null,
  "_id": "517d2dcf377dcffc11000009"
}
```

I got the following behavior :

- When the user filled in a latitude / longitude and clicks the save button, he returned to the overview to find his newly created record twice in the overview.
- After clicking save, an error was shown in the console : Your server returned a hash with the key latitude but you have no mapping for it.
- Refreshing the page got rid of the duplicate.

I was able to solve this by returning the ember.js standard JSON after doing a POST

```
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": "1.123",
    "longitude": "1.123",
    "accuracy": null,
    "_id": "517d31457b40fcbc2a000003"
  }
}
```

The app is configured to use _id as a primary key as I'm using mongodb.

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function (type){
      return '_id';
   }
  })
});
```

I can now understand why Ember.js complained about the latitude key (as it was expecting a location root element), but I don't understand why it added the model twice to the collection (using only 1 POST)

So 2 questions :

- What is wrong with my flow and how can I fix it ?
- Why did I end up with duplicates when the REST api returned non-ember.js standard JSON.

Comment: Did you configure a `primaryKey` in your serializer to `_id`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I think I'm running into a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670855/uncommitted-record-still-present-after-rollback

Answer (score 1):

**Model store transactions**

Wrap your creation into a new transaction. This won't prevent the record to be visible in the list (you can always filter your list to reject new records). In your router, you can rollback the transaction when exiting the state. Something like:

```
App.LocationsNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.transaction = DS.defaultStore.transaction(),
  },

  model: function() {
    return this.transaction.createRecord(App.Location);
  }
});
```

In your `save` handler, you want to commit the record's transaction (and not the store's default one).

UPDATE: do not rollback on `deactivate`

**Model duplicates**

"Your server returned a hash with the key latitude but you have no mapping for it." Ember data tried to sideload each attribute/key that was returned in your JSON. Ember data expects the returned object to be under a root key in your JSON (as you have noticed).

I don't know why you had duplicates.

UPDATE 2: how to not display newly created records

I said something wrong in my comments, records created within a transaction belong to the array returned by `find`. I forgot that I have updated my code to do it:

```
App.LocationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  persisted: function() {
    return this.get('arrangedContent').filter( function(contact) {
      if( !contact.get('isNew') ) {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }.property('arrangedContent.@each.isNew', 'arrangedContent')
})
```

And then in your template:

```
{{#each persisted}}
  // whatever you need
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Does an Ember.JS "new record" page really force you to actually create the new record ? Is the filtering really necessary and if so, how do I filter ? Seems strange ... if a user clicks 100 times on my "new record" button, I don't want to have 100 empty objects in my transaction.

Comment: You can rollback the transaction in `deactivate` if the record hasn't been saved

Comment: Tried the solution and although the deactivate is called when navigating away from the LocationsNewRoute  route, when returning to my LocationsIndexRoute, the App.location.find() method still returns the item that I was working on (but not saving) in the locations/new template.

Comment: But If I don't rollback the "new record" is still in the list. What would be the correct way of filtering out that record ? In fact, I think I want to do a rollback here, as the user obviously decided to "not save" the record and start doing something else in the app.

Comment: A record created in a transaction doesn't show up in the list of all records returned by `find` as long as it has never been saved. So this shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Cyril - If the user started typing in the "new record" page it does end up in the list and find() returns it. Most likely due to the value binding.  How do you define "never been saved" ?