# Uncommitted record still present after rollback()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following in an ObjectController and have verified that both actions are called correctly:

```
setup: ->
  transaction = @get('store').transaction()
  post = transaction.createRecord(App.Post, {postedAt: new Date()})
  @set('content', post)

cancel: ->
  @get('content.transaction').rollback()
```

However, despite the transaction being rolled back the uncommitted record is still present in the data store.

Should I be handling created records differently in transactions?

**Edit:** I'm also seeing errors such as this after rolling back the transaction:

```
Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <App.Post:ember926:null> while in state rootState.deleted.saved. Called with {name: title}
```

Comment: I had to work around this by using {{#unless isDeleted}} in my list view. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong but the workaround doesn't appear to be needed when I do something similar in a JSFiddle.

Comment: I also have this problem, can you tell me how to fix it?